# preApproval data is required

Tags: python, python-requests

Atualmente, estou tentando integrar um pré-pagamento via v2 do api para pagseguro. Por alguma razão eu continuo recebendo dados pré-aprovação é necessária. Eu tentei chaning os cabeçalhos, eu também estava verificando o exemplo na documentação e não parecem estar faltando nada. Alguém pode lançar alguma luz sobre o que eu poderia estar faltando?

```
import requests
data = request.form
pagseguro_url = app_config.PAG_SEGURO['pageseguroUrl']
email = app_config.PAG_SEGURO['email']
token = app_config.PAG_SEGURO['token']
currency = app_config.PAG_SEGURO['currency']
item_id = data['itemId']
item_description = app_config.ITEMS[item_id]['itemDescription']
item_amount = app_config.ITEMS[item_id]['itemAmount']
item_quantity = app_config.ITEMS[item_id]['itemQuantity']
reference = data['reference']
sender_email = data['senderEmail']
redirect_url = app_config.PAG_SEGURO['redirectUrl']
if app_config.ITEMS[item_id]['preApproval']:
    d = datetime.utcnow()
    date = "%s-%02d-%02d" % (d.year, d.month, d.day)
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1', 'Accept':'application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1'}
    r = requests.post("https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request?email=%s&token=%s" % (email, token), headers=headers, data={
              'redirectUrl': redirect_url,
              'reference': reference,
              "preApproval": {
                "name": item_description,
                "charge": "AUTO",
                "period": "MONTHLY",
                "amountPerPayment": item_amount,
                "expiration": {
                  "value": 24,
                  "unit": "MONTHS"
                },
                "details": "string",
                "maxAmountPerPeriod": item_amount,
                "maxAmountPerPayment": item_amount,
                "maxTotalAmount": 360,
                "maxPaymentsPerPeriod": 1,
                # "initialDate": date,
                "finalDate": date,
                "cancelURL": "https://dev.domain.com/settings/premium"
              },
              "maxUses": 1000,
              "receiver": {
                'email': email
              }
            })
```

Mas quando eu executá-lo eu recebo este erro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?><errors><error><code>11101</code><message>preApproval data is required.</message></error></errors>
```

Também eu tentei mudar a codificação e aceito cabeçalhos, mas tenho um mau cabeçalhos de solicitação aceitos.

```
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1', 'Accept':'application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1'}
    r = requests.post("https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request?email=%s&token=%s"
                      % (email, token), headers=headers, data={
                'redirectUrl': redirect_url,
                'reference': reference,
                "preApproval": {
                    "name": "stuff",
                    "charge": "AUTO",
                    "period": "MONTHLY",
                    "amountPerPayment": item_amount,
                    "expiration": {
                        "value": 2,
                        "unit": "YEARS"
                    }
                },
                "receiver": {
                    "email": 'hola@blah.com'
                }

            })
```

Mas este código de erro `415` retornos

```
 </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Cannot consume content type</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Cannot consume content type).</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA</h3></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação [Pagamento Recorrente Transparente](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/documentacao/pagamentos/pagamento-recorrente-transparente) você deve utilizar os seguinte `headers`:

- `Content-Type` `application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1` para enviar dados em formato `JSON`. Da maneira que você está informando (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1`) os dados deveriam ser enviados na `URL`;
- `Accept` `application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+json;charset=ISO-8859-1` para enviar `JSON`. No seu exemplo você está informando `application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v3+xml;charset=ISO-8859-1` que é referente a `XML`;

Note também que não tem o `/v2` na `URL` descrita na documentação, então para `sandbox` ficaria `https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pre-approvals/request?email=%s&token=%s‌`.

Quanto aos dados enviados, você está enviando mais campos do que o solicitado. Os dados de envio para criar um plano pré-pago com cobranças mensais de R$ 100,00 durante 2 anos devem seguir o seguinte modelo:

```
{
  "preApproval": {
    "name": "Assinatura da Revista Fictícia",
    "charge": "AUTO",
    "period": "MONTHLY",
    "amountPerPayment": 100.00,
    "expiration": {
      "value": 2,
      "unit": "YEARS"
    }
  },
  "receiver": {
    "email": "seu@email.com.br"
  }
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas simplesmente Em vez disso retorna ao código de erro 415. Eu atualizei a questão de mostrar o que eu tentei

Comment: acaba de atualizar, por favor, verifique

Comment: Que retorna o mesmo erro Passado

Comment: e eu fiz, este atualizada abaixo do original

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54446/discussion-between-nadermx-and-sorack).